# Как это работает? Добавление массива в список

Tags: java, массивы, list

В процессе изучения Java столкнулся с ситуацией которая меня поставила в ступор.
Мне нужно был список из массивов [0, 0] [0, 1] [0, 2] [0, 3] [1, 0] [1, 1] и так далее до [3, 3]
Не долго думая написал такой код

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ArrayList<int[]> field = new ArrayList<>();
        int[] cell = new int[2];
        for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < 4 ; j++) {
                cell[0] = i;
                cell[1] = j;
                field.add(cell);
            }
        }
        for(int[] array: field){
            System.out.print(Arrays.toString(array) + " ");
        }
    }
}
```

В итоге я получил список:

```
[3, 3] [3, 3] [3, 3] [3, 3] [3, 3] [3, 3] [3, 3] [3, 3] [3, 3] [3, 3] [3, 3] [3, 3] [3, 3] [3, 3] [3, 3] [3, 3]
```

Т.е. после каждой итерации цикла не просто добавлялся какой то конкретный элемент в конец списка, а менялся весь список! 
Каким образом? Как это происходит?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Как это работает?

Вы создаете объект:

`int[] cell = new int[2];`

Далее, в цикле, Вы меняете его состояние и добавляете его в список. На последующих итерациях цикла Вы изменяете тот же самый объект и добавляете его в список. В итоге у Вас в списке на разных позициях находится один и тот же объект.

Для решения данной проблемы **создавайте новый объект на каждой итерации цикла**:

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ArrayList<int[]> field = new ArrayList<>();

        for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < 4 ; j++) {
                int[] cell = new int[2];
                cell[0] = i;
                cell[1] = j;
                field.add(cell);
            }
        }
        for(int[] array: field){
            System.out.print(Arrays.toString(array) + " ");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Т.е. в моем примере field.get(i) ссылается на один и тот же массив?

Comment: @Олег, Совершенно верно.